# How to define style to layout-margin flex variants, using Angular Material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to have different margins for flex and flex-sm tags:

```
    <div layout="row" layout-margin layout-wrap>
      <div flex="30" flex-sm="100" ng-repeat="occasion in
          resultObject.occasionTypes[typeIndex].occasions">
            ------------
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to use something like:

```
[layout-margin] > [flex] {
    margin: 3px; }

[layout-margin] > [flex-sm] {
    margin: 0px; }
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular material doesn't add or remove the attributes based on the browser size, so both [flex] and [flex-sm] will always be on your element. That is why they both apply, you will have to write a media query with the same break point as angular material if you want to accomplish this:

```
[layout-margin] > [flex] {
    margin: 3px; 
}

@media (max-width: 599px){
    [layout-margin] > [flex-sm] {
        margin: 0; 
    }
}
```